# Change image due to the css of display jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change an image on the fact of the CSS of `.slidingDiv`.
This is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $('.slidingDiv').css({'display':'none'});
    var b = $('.slidingDiv').css({'display' : 'table-row'});

    if (a > b) {
        a.find('.imgchange img').attr('src','http://illiweb.com/fa/m/tabs_less1.gif');
    } else  if (a<b){
        $('.imgchange img').attr('src','http://illiweb.com/fa/m/tabs_more1.gif');
    }
});​
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I am trying to make the `tabs_more1.gif` appear if the div is closed (`display:none;`) and the `tabs_less1.gif` appear if they are opened (`display:table-row;`

Code to open and close the divs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slidingDiv").hide();  
$('.secondarytitle').click(function() {  
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(); 
});  
  });
```

Comment: Why are you comparing `a` and `b`? They're not numbers.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons this code doesn't work.  Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yea I'm not sure this is doing what you need. Based on the image name it looks like you want to swap out a less or more image if the div is visible or not - is that correct? If so your if should check for :visible

Comment: a and b need to be a numbers? This is first time using if else on a code like this. so we can't do this `a>b`?

Comment: edited the above to explain more guys

Comment: do you have mulitple `.slidingDiv` elements or just one ? (*and if multiple*) are there also multiple `.imgchange` elements ?*). Maybe you could also post the relevant html so we can see the big picture ..

Comment: The markup would be hard to post since it is parsed through php. Yes to both, multiple `.slidingDiv` and `.imgchange` elements
Maybe check out the site for now, www.thegamerspodium.forumotion.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just test for the visibility of the `.slidingDiv`.

In your code, `a` and `b` are returning jQuery itself, not numbers.  [jQuery.fn.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) passed with two arguments or an object as its first argument will set the CSS to your 2nd argument's string value or object's value.  You are hiding your `slidingDiv` element, and then showing it again so fast the eye probably wouldn't notice it.  jQuery is being returned so you can [chain methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#jQuery) together.

What you want to do depends on *when* you want to do it.

If you want to change the image **after**, provide a callback function as the second argument  to [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) in your code.  It is the function that executes when `.slidingDiv` stops sliding/animating.  Within the function you can check for anything you want after that; it is guaranteed that your div will either be fully displayed or fully hidden and that jQuery will correctly evaluate the currently applied CSS styles to `.slidingDiv`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();  
    $('.secondarytitle').click(function() {  
        $(this).closest('tr').siblings('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(undefined, changeImage); 
    });  
});

function changeImage() {
    var slidingEl = $('.slidingDiv'),
        isVisibleBool = slidingEl.is(':visible'),
        imgToChangeEl = $('.imgchange img');

    if (true === isVisibleBool) {
        imgToChangeEl.attr('src','http://illiweb.com/fa/m/tabs_less1.gif');
    } else {
        imgToChangeEl.attr('src','http://illiweb.com/fa/m/tabs_more1.gif');
    }
}
```

If you want to change the image **before**, put the `changeImage` call before the `slideToggle` call.  You can save the callback function for another day.  However, note that [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) does accept a callback function as a parameter.

Comment: this code changes them to the tabs_more1 but when opened it doesn't change em to the less1.gif?

Comment: You're going to have to add an event handler to when it's opened.  Or wrap the code in a setInterval/setTimeout.

Comment: @danronmoon, do you have code that opens/closes the divs ? if so edit you question and add that code as well

Comment: I do have code that opens and closes, i believe @GabyakaG.Petrioli was talking to me :) and an event handler like so onClick=""

Comment: sorry.. yes i was referring to @user1760670 (*i messed the names*)

Answer (score 4):

First

```
var a = $('.slidingDiv').css({'display':'none'});
var b = $('.slidingDiv').css({'display' : 'table-row'});
```

These two line target the same elements, so the second is overriding what the first one does.

---

Then you are comparing `(a > b)`. What do you expect from this ? you are comparing two jquery objects (*with the same contents at this moment*)

---

In the `else` you do

```
('.imgchange img').
```

You seem to be missing the `$` at the start..

Comment: oops about the $, though I figured they were different variables since I change the display from none to table-row